# Converting string to raw bytes

Tags: python, arrays, string, byte

I wrote a program that works with raw bytes (I don't know if this is the right name!) but the user will input the data as plain strings.

How to convert them?

I've tried wih a method but it returns a string with length 0!

Here's the starting string:

```
5A05705DC25CA15123C8E4750B80D0A9
```

Here's the result that I need:

```
\x5A\x05\x70\x5D\xC2\x5C\xA1\x51\x23\xC8\xE4\x75\x0B\x80\xD0\xA9
```

And here's the method I wrote:

```
def convertStringToByte(string):
    byte_char = "\\x"
    n=2
    result = ""
    bytesList = [string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
    for i in range(0, len(bytesList)):
        bytesList[i] = byte_char + bytesList[i]
    return result
```

Comment: how about `return ''.join(bytesList)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`binascii.unhexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
import binascii

binary = binascii.unhexlify(text)
```

The same module has [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) too, to mirror the operation.

Demo:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binary = '\x5A\x05\x70\x5D\xC2\x5C\xA1\x51\x23\xC8\xE4\x75\x0B\x80\xD0\xA9'
>>> text = '5A05705DC25CA15123C8E4750B80D0A9'
>>> binary == binascii.unhexlify(text)
True
>>> text == binascii.hexlify(binary).upper()
True
```

The `hexlify()` operation produces *lowercase* hex, but that is easily fixed with a `.upper()` call.

Answer (score 4):

You must get from `5A` (a string representing an hexidecimal number) to `0x5A` or `90` (integers) and feed them into `chr()`. You can do the first conversion with `int('0x5A', 16)`, so you'll get something like

```
chr(int('0x5A', 16))
```